# show index/position of element on click JQuery/HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I have a number of call to actions on a page with the same classname (button) as follows:

```
<div class="topClass">
    <div class="classNameone">
        <p>bit of schpiel about section 1</p>
        <a href="#" class="Button">click me!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="classNametwo">
        <p>bit of schpiel about section 2</p>
        <a href="#" class="Button">click me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want jQuery to tell me which link i'm clicking on when i click on it without me having to add another class or ID.

e.g. 1 for the first button and 2 for the second (or 0 and 1 depending on the index start).

i've tried using the following on the click of the element:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.Button').index(this)
```

but all that is being returned is -1.

any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Actually your example works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Alshten/PtB2q/

Comment: So it does, I think the structure that i'm currenty working on must be a little more complicated as Rajaprabhu's answer below is giving me the same issue.  I'll keep plugging, at least I know my theory is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will return the `index` of the clicked `anchor` element in the perspective of the `div` with class `topClass`.

Try this,

```
$('a').click(function(){    
    alert($(this).closest('div').index() +1 );
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d9Xa3/1/)

Reference : [.Closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)